# Typed property App\Entity\XXXX ::$users must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I encounter the following problem when try to run my fixtures with Symfony 6 and php 8.1:

```
Typed property App\Entity\XXXX ::$users must not be accessed before initialization
```

Here is my fixture file which uses the user :

```
    <?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\UserGroup;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class UserGroupFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
          LicenseFixtures::class,
          UserFixtures::class
        ];
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $user = $this->getReference(UserFixtures::FIRST_USER);
        $license = $this->getReference(LicenseFixtures::FIRST_LICENSE);
        $userGroup = new UserGroup();
        $userGroup->addUser($user);
        $userGroup->setOwnerUser($user->getId());
        $userGroup->setNumberOfUsers(1);
        $userGroup->setLicense($license);
        $manager->persist($userGroup);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

But fixtures stop working or I don't understand each fixture file has a getOrder to define the order of execution and use the references.

For me the user is however well initialized. Does anyone have any clues on how to solve this puzzle?

UserFixture

```
 <?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\User;
use DateTimeImmutable;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

class UserFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public const FIRST_USER = 'user';



    public function __construct(UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher)
    {
        $this->userPasswordHasher = $userPasswordHasher;
    }


    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $user = new User();
        $hashPassword =  $this->userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
            $user,
            "test"
        );

        $user->setFirstName('robert');
        $user->setLastName('damoret');
        $user->setEmail('test@gmail.com');
        $user->setIpAddress('12.12.12.12');
        $user->setPassword($hashPassword);
        $user->setCreatedAt(new DateTimeImmutable());
        $user->setUpdatedAt(new DateTimeImmutable());
        $user->setStatus("CHECK");

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
        $this->addReference(self::FIRST_USER, $user);
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show UserFixtures Class please

Comment: @YohannDanielCarter I add them in the post

Comment: Class `XXXX` has a property called `$users` which you attempt to read before assigning any value to it ([demo](https://3v4l.org/GAqYE)). I don't know how that relates to the code you've shared because code is anonymised and you haven't shared any entity class definition.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm not sure I understand what you're saying the user entity is a defined class, I can't share it here because it's very meaningful. I start by creating my user in the fixture UserFixture. this user I want to reuse it in my usergroup fixture which logically already has the user registered in the database from where the reference is made.

Comment: [The property is uninitialized](https://php.watch/versions/7.4/typed-properties#uninitialized)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely in your entity constructor method, where you need to initialize the users field as an array collection.

```php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

#[Entity]
class UserGroup
{
    // ...
    
    #[OneToMany(targetEntity: User::class, mappedBy: '...')]
    private Collection $users;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional